# Selecting a polygon within polygon where part of its boundary is the same. PostGIS

Tags: postgis, select, select-by-attribute, select-by-location

I would like to know how can I select a A_polygon within B_polygon, but part of the boundary of the A_polygon touch the B_polygon boundary. In Postgis 2.0, I tried few options but they didn´t work (st_contains, st_containsproperly, st_intersect, etc.).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul Ramsey, thanks for your answers. Now I see it clear 'as mud' ... hehee

From this disadvantage I tried understand the problem and make the best solution possible:

If we are sure that we intersected correctly (I mean like the above example) I found a possible solution:

SELECT 
 polygonA.field, polygonB.field 
FROM
 polygonA, polygonB
WHERE
 polygonB.ID= 1
AND
 ST_Contains(polygonB.geom,ST_PointtoSurface(polygonA.geom));

The reason of ST_Centroid doesn´t work is because the result of ST_Centroid can to obtain a point outside of the polygon. To force this point inside of the polygon we need use ST_PointotSurface.

To say ArcMap use the function 'Feature to Point' and it has a option to force the centroid point inside of the polygon.

Thanks again, Paul.

Answer (score 0):

ST_Contains would seem to do what you want (find that A is in B, but that C is not) It'll also find that A is in A, but that's easy to filter out by adding an "id not equals" test to the query. If you're finding that contains is not doing what you want, you need to look very closely at that boundary, your geometry edges are probably not exactly coincident. If a loose relation is good enough, try just testing the ST_Contains(B,ST_Centroid(A))

Comment: To say that I obtained the polygons A and C by intersect with B (before A and C were a single polygon).I'm definitely not looking ST_Contains because the result of ST_Contains is null.

If I use ST_Intersects I obtain the polygon A and C because the have the same part of boundary.

Comment: Just because you got A by intersecting doesn't mean that it's boundary is strictly on or within B. Sad but true. The new corner points of A generated at the intersection might not fall exactly on the line that joins the corder of B. (What?!?!?) Because of numerical precision. The edge of B between the corners doesn't exist, it's a mathematical abstraction. The corners of A, on the other hand, *do* exist, and have to be represented in the IEEE double precision grid, which might not have any points that fall exactly on the path of the edge of B. Clear as mud? Should be, it's hard!